# Recursive startActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity

I am studying developing for android. It's only example project. So I am creating the same Activity on button click event (see code). After first Activity I can see new Activity with "qwerty" text, but on next clicking text stays the same. I expected to see more text after every new click ("qwerty", "qwerty qwerty", "qwerty qwerty qwerty" and so on). How to explain that behavior?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView _textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    _textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.hasExtra("str"))
    {
        _textView.setText(_textView.getText().toString() + " qwerty");
    }
}

public void onShowActivityButtonClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("str", _textView.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: Try to check this way : if(intent.getStringExtra("str")!=null)

Comment: @Sartre: have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

with

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: Sorry, I forget about this question. No, it is not working. In this case even a new MainActivity doesn't starts.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `onShowActivityButtonClick` method:

```
public void onShowActivityButtonClick(View view){

    Intent intent = getIntent(); //Get current activity
    intent.putExtra("str", _textView.getText().toString());

    finish(); //Close current activity
    startActivity(intent); //Restart current activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
_textView.setText(_textView.getText().toString() + " qwerty");
```

with

```
_textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("str") + " qwerty");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this peace of code :

```
if(intent.hasExtra("str"))
{
  _textView.setText(_textView.getText().toString() + " qwerty");
}
```

With this :

```
if(intent.hasExtra("str"))
{
   _textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("str"));
}else{
   _textView.setText("qwerty");
}
```

**AND**

Change this peace of code :

```
intent.putExtra("str", _textView.getText().toString());
```

With this :

```
intent.putExtra("str", tv.getText().toString()+" qwerty");
```